# How to display two queries results to one

Tags: mysql, sql, join, merge

I have two mysql queries, which are giving me different data for same type of columns. Now I would like to merge these two results as single. below are my queries.

query-1:

```
SELECT cl.cand_corp_id as corpId, cl.shortlisted_timestamp as updatedDate, count(1) as activityCount
FROM candidates_log cl
where cl.shortlisted_timestamp > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
group by cl.cand_corp_id
order by cl.shortlisted_timestamp desc
```

result 1: 
[image]

Query-2:

```
select j.corp_id as corpId, j.created_at as updatedDate, count(1) as activityCount
from jobs j
where j.created_at > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
group by j.corp_id
order by activityCount, j.created_at desc limit 5
```

Result-2;
[image]

How can i get the final result with union of these two result sets.

Comment: Show the result you need. If the same pair of `corpId,  updatedDate` is present in both resultsets, do you need to sum `activityCount` or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use UNION ALL

```
select * from (
You could use union all  
SELECT cl.cand_corp_id as corpId, cl.shortlisted_timestamp as updatedDate, count(1) as activityCount
FROM candidates_log cl
where cl.shortlisted_timestamp > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
group by cl.cand_corp_id
order by cl.shortlisted_timestamp desc
) t1

Union ALL 

select * from ( 
select j.corp_id as corpId, j.created_at as updatedDate, count(1) as activityCount
from jobs j
where j.created_at > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
group by j.corp_id
order by activityCount, j.created_at desc limit 5
) t2
order by activityCount, updatedDate
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try UNION ALL (should be between those two queries). If type of columns/data are the same it should work.

```
SELECT cl.cand_corp_id as corpId, cl.shortlisted_timestamp as updatedDate, count(1) as activityCount
FROM candidates_log cl
WHERE cl.shortlisted_timestamp > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
GROUP BY cl.cand_corp_id
ORDER BY cl.shortlisted_timestamp desc
UNION ALL
SELECT j.corp_id as corpId, j.created_at as updatedDate, count(1) as activityCount
FROM jobs j
WHERE j.created_at > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
GROUP BY j.corp_id
ORDER BY activityCount, j.created_at desc limit 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use UNION ALL Statement :

( SELECT cl.cand_corp_id as corpId, cl.shortlisted_timestamp as updatedDate,    
  count(1) as activityCount
  FROM candidates_log cl
  where cl.shortlisted_timestamp > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
  group by cl.cand_corp_id
  order by cl.shortlisted_timestamp desc

)
UNION ALL
(
   select j.corp_id as corpId, j.created_at as updatedDate, count(1) as  
   activityCount
   from jobs j
   where j.created_at > DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY)
   group by j.corp_id
) 
ORDER BY updatedDate LIMIT 5
```